# Centering variable width captions on flexbox elements

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to center captions on flexbox elements? I've only been able to center when I have the captions contribute to the parent's width, but that messes up the distance between the flexbox elements.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[flexbox with variable captions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWZHh.png)

Comment: You're supposed to give us some code to work with (html + css).
[Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ack, i didn't realize that. thanks for the info. regardless, i just found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do what I needed.

You can center captions with the following:

```
.caption-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```